# Linking a SWIG wrapper with other libraries

Tags: c++, python, gcc, swig

I have a C++ function that I want to call from Python. The function itself is pretty simple, but it involves an IPC call that can only be done in C++. To compile that C++ code requires linking a ton of other libraries in. I'm trying to use SWIG for this. I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
all: swig object shared

object: swig
  ${CC} -c ${MODULE}_wrap.cxx ${INCLUDES}

shared:
  ${CC} -Wl,--verbose -shared ${MODULE}_wrap.o -o _${MODULE}.so

swig:
  ${SWIG} -c++ -python ${MODULE}.i
```

With this, everything compiles fine, but then importing my module in Python gives me "undefined symbol" errors. If I change the `shared` line to:

```
shared:
  ${CC} -Wl,--verbose -shared ${MODULE}_wrap.o -o _${MODULE}.so ${LIBS}
```

it fails to compile with `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` but doesn't tell me exactly what the error is. The verbose linker output has a ton of lines that say "attempt to open [some lib] failed" but a handful of those lines say "succeeded". Could it just be the ones that say failed are preventing linking from happening? Is what I'm trying to do even possible with SWIG modules?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You need to make sure the shared libraries your wrapped C/C++ module depends on are resolved when Python loads the module. Check the library (Swig generated) with `ldd` to see what libs it depends on. It is best to set up rpath (runtime path; something like: `-rpath=/path/to/your/libs` for gcc) to point to those libs' location(s) when you link your module. Alternatively you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately before running Python.

Comment: I can't do an `ldd` on the SWIG generated library because it's just an  object file. But I tried this anyway. `-rpath=` didn't work, but I tried `-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker [path]`. I also tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I still get the undefined symbol error. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling with SWIG try this in a terminal:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/where/library/is_located/lib
$ python
```

then you would be able to import your module from python.